# events that can be used for free drawing

Tags: canvas, c++builder, mousedown

I'm trying to make a free drawing program with c++ builder and graphics32 component.

Usually people use mousedown, mousemove, mouseup events to make this kind of program
but it doesn't work well when I tried drawing with a tablet.

I find out mouseup event occur twice when the tablet pen isn't recognized well,
so the mousemove event that draw pictures using lineto while mousedown occurs is not executed.

My question is

1. Are there any events that I can use instead of mousedown, mousemove, mouseup for drawing on Bitmap->Canvas?

Comment: "*Are there any events that ...*" - in a word, no.  You should find out why you are getting erroneous `MouseUp` events and fix that (or report the issue to the pen manufacturer and get a better driver). That said, there are other *messages* or *APIs* that you can use instead. Have you looked at [Pen Input, Ink, and Recognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tablet/pen-input--ink--and-recognition) yet? Why replicate manually what the OS already provides?

Comment: Actually I'm not making just free drawing program but making a program in which students and teachers exchange content with each other in real time using the same blackboard. The program is almost done except the error described above...so errorless drawing is needed. Thanks a lot anyway! I'll try to fix a Mouseup event problem. @Remy Lebeau

Comment: Do you have the same problem with events if you use a mouse hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `RegisterRawInputDevices()`?